# How to simply increase probability of an event?

Tags: probability

Lets say there is **40%** chance that an event will happen. Than it is said that the probability of the event is increased by five times. I do realize that the resulting percentage is not 200% or even 100%.

I do however assume, that the result will be 1 - (1 - 40%) / 5 = **88%** (instead of increasing the probability, I decrease the opposite).

Now, is that correct? If not, what formula will calculate the new chance of the event depending on the probability multiplication?

Comment: I think you're trying to extract a precise meaning from wild hyperbole. Don't waste your time.

Comment: I think you'll have to define "increasing the probability by five times" rigorously first before proceeding with your investigation.

Comment: can it be $45\%$?

Comment: @Lost I do not very strong in math, however I'll try: by another meaning, the chance of that the event will happen is **five times** more likely than before.

Comment: This is similar to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/465718)

Comment: I understand what you meant, but with a question like that, you need to be able to define it rigorously in mathematical terms in order to understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the reasoning in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/465751), we get the odds to be $2/3:1$ and $5\times2/3=10/3$. The probability of an event with odds of $10/3:1$ is $10/13=76.923\%$